# Angular 5: adding types to external JS file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I'm loading a JS file through a `<script src="http://.../script.js">`

In the JS, there is a namespace "foo", and a method "bar".

I would like to call `foo.bar()` from my component.

I'd like to add type definitions so that I know what I'm doing while I'm coding. I have the file `script.d.ts` with type definitions. It looks like this:

```
export as namespace foo;

export namespace Baz {
    interface Qux {
    // ...
    }
}

export function bar(): Baz.Qux;
```

I can't figure out how to include this file in the Angular build (using CLI), so that I get type checks during build, but at runtime the namespace and function in the external JS file will be called from my component. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the export modifier, since these are not exported from a module you can use `declare` and reference them with a `///` or include the definitions in `tsconfig`:

```
// script.d.ts
declare namespace foo {
    namespace Baz {
        interface Qux {
        // ...
        }
    }

    declare function bar(): Baz.Qux;
}

// Other file
/// <reference path="./script.d.ts" />
foo.bar() // works and calls method from remote JS file
```

Comment: the namespace "foo" is being used in my script.js, so I'm forced to use `foo.bar()` though.

Comment: @LuisAceituno the  wrap it all in the `foo` namespace edited answer